# Laravel com painel laravel-admin

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, controller, radiobutton

sou iniciante com o Laravel e estou utilizando o Laravel 5.3 com o Painel de Administração chamado laravel-admin (https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin)

Estou necessitando obter a resposta de um radio-button com Ajax antes de submeter o form.

A situação é assim:

Usa Medicamentos? ()Sim ()Não

Se ele marcar Sim, então eu tenho que perguntar qual ou quais medicamentos ele toma.

O select funciona e armazena numa boa, mas não consigo fazer com que o form que é genérico para todos implemente uma div ou algo semelhante que dependendo da resposta eu mostre ou não a próxima pergunta.

O meu código atual é:

```
/**
 * Make a form builder.
 *
 * @return Form
 */
protected function form()
{
    return Admin::form(Aluno::class, function (Form $form) {

        $form->display('id', 'ID');
        $form->text('Matricula','Matrícula')->rules('required|min:5');
        $form->text('Nome','Nome do Aluno')->rules('required|min:4|max:50');

        $form->radio('ReacaoAlergica','Possui reação alérgica a algum medicamento?')->options([1=>'Sim',0=>'Não'])->ajax('/Admin/Extensions/Tools/remedios');
        // Se a resposta for Não então a próxima linha não pode ser mostrada
        $form->multipleSelect('medicamentos')->options(Medicamento::all()->pluck('Nome', 'id'));



        $form->divide();

        $form->number('idRespFinanceiro','Cod. do Responsável Financeiro');
        $form->display('created_at', 'Criado Em');
        $form->display('updated_at', 'Atualizado Em');
    });
}
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como ajudar? Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução seria você fazer esse controle com javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="ReacaoAlergica"]').forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener('click', function() {
    div_medicamentos.style.display = ReacaoAlergicaS.checked ? '' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
Possui reação alérgica a algum medicamento?
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="ReacaoAlergicaS" name="ReacaoAlergica" value="1">
  <label for="ReacaoAlergicaS">Sim</label>

  <input type="radio" id="ReacaoAlergicaN" name="ReacaoAlergica" value="0">
  <label for="ReacaoAlergicaN">Não</label>
</div>

<div id="div_medicamentos" style="display: none">
  <label for="quais"> </label>
  <select name="medicamentos" >
    <option>Escolha o medicamento</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

No exemplo eu primeiro procuro por elementos que tenham o name igual a ReacaoAlergica depois eu faço um loop com esses elementos para atribuir um evento de click, toda vez que um deles é clicado eu faço uma checagem para ver se a opção sim está marcada, caso ela esteja eu tiro a propriedade none do style para que a div apareça, caso contrário eu adiciono o none para que ela fique oculta!

Se você tiver usando jQuery o exemplo pode diminuir um pouco:

```
$('[name="ReacaoAlergica"]').click(function() {
    div_medicamentos.style.display = ReacaoAlergicaS.checked ? '' : 'none';
});
```

OBS.: Você deve colocar todos os ids e names como eu coloquei no exemplo, para que o código funcione corretamente.

Comment: Junior, obrigado por responder, porém este painel não tem uma área de View padrão que é gerado para cada controller e sim um blade que fica em vendor\encore\views\form.blade.php, então se eu alterar estarei alterando para todos os forms. Você conhece alguma forma de passar isso via Controller? Chamar uma requisição para incluir isso na View?

Comment: Você pode passar uma variável do seu controlador pra view, e na view checar se essa variável existe, se existir tu adiciona o código acima, vai funcionar...

Comment: Ok, vou testar e coloco o resultado. Obrigado pela força